# Yii2 migration "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2, foreign-keys

This is how I have added the foreign key inside of the migration:

```
$this->addForeignKey(
        'fk-auth_item_ibfk_1',
        'auth_item',
        'rule_name',
        'auth_rule',
        'name',
        'SET NULL',
        'CASCADE'
    );
```

Exception:

```
Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `yii`.`#sql-1ab_85` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Error Info:

```
Error Info:
Array
(
[0] => HY000
[1] => 1005
[2] => Can't create table `yii`.`#sql-1ab_af` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
)
```

Any help is appreciated. I haven't got a clue why its happening. I have checked that the fields are of same type and size.

Comment: Make sure the fields 'rule_name' and 'name' have the same type and/or length (for example, both INT(11))

Comment: They are, was the first thing I checked - other than that I have absolutely no idea

Comment: I think there is an issue with the defined constraint `'fk-auth_item_ibfk_1'` can you change it to `fk_auth_item_ibfk_1` and check.

Comment: haha @davey thinking alike :D

Comment: same error @ShahrozeNawaz. I have just added the error info if that helps

Comment: The name of FK is fine. Maybe one table is MyISAM and other is InnoDB?